# The right way of managing Multiple files of typescript for a website

Tags: typescript, browser

I have a big project that has multiple JavaScript files with a common code that, obviously, gets bigger and uglier.

I want to change the Javascript code to Typescript so it'll be easier to maintain and link these typescript files to one another but I couldn't find a good (and easy?) way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found out that using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) can be elegant and efficient. It works with a config file and supports hot-reload (refreshing the page when one of the files has changed) and babel transpile from TypeScript to an old version of JavaScript etc.